# Regarding Nagios Monitoring Server - Windows Host down

Tags: server, nagios

I have configured Nagios Monitoring Server in CentOS. After configuration done , i have added the Windows host to that server. Change the configurations for host connection, server definitions in that server.

But Ping is done , the windows host is showing down and the services are showing unknown.

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you running the service nsclient++.exe on windows.

Comment: Yes.I have installed NSclient++ and checked the service is running or not.But also failed to notify the service status.

Answer (score 0):

I installed nsclient++ and configured my windows host details in nagios.cfg,command.cfg and windows.cfg files.But the services are showing unknown.